# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.recover

Tags: android, android-ksoap2, okhttp

I have an application which uses ksoap with an underlying `okhttp` connection.

The majority of the time it works  - however during a connection retry the application crashes with a NoSuchMethodError. Stack trace below

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.recover
     at okhttp3.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:493)
     at okhttp3.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
     at okhttp3.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:261)
     at org.ksoap2.transport.OkHttpServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(OkHttpServiceConnectionSE.java:124)
     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.sendData(HttpTransportSE.java:292)
     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:184)
     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
     at uk.org.xibo.xmds.CheckConnection.run(CheckConnection.java:106)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I do use proguard, and have added rules so that okhttp is left alone:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
```

My grade file contains these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
```

I have tried decompiling the resulting APK and can confirm that the `okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.recover` method does exist.

The source for the missing method is here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/huc/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java#L495

I am not sure how to proceed debugging this issue OR whether I have done something obviously wrong.

Thanks for any assistance.

---

EDIT:

New theory - ksoap2-android has [a reference](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/1528b0f63a9fedaddc0f8b7c47e615e77a76f263/ksoap2-j2se/pom.xml#L32) to part of the okhttp library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp-urlconnection</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The `HttpEngine` method is contained in the main okhttp library - could it be that **my** reference to okhttp v3.3.0 is providing the `HttpEngine` which is being used by `HttpURLConnectionImpl` v3.2.0 from the ksoap2 library?

I've downgraded my okhttp dependency to `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'` and have installed on a few devices to test. If this is the problem I will update with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the delay - reverting to `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'` in my gradle file did solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, by downgrading okhttp dependency to ````compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'```` only works.

Answer (score 0):

Update it to the latest version: `implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1")`. It helped in my case.